# how to solve Netwrok Error ,AxiosError: Network Error in React js

Tags: error-handling, runtime-error

I am using React. js in laptop and when I try to call axios. get , I get Network Error. I read many other cases like mine who were using React network errors in ReactJS applications?
Uncaught run time errror:
Network error .axios error

Comment: This question is incomplete. Do share your code here to get specific answer.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Install axios

```
npm install axios
```

Write this code in component where you're making the axios.get request.
Write actual API endpoint you are fetching dtaa from in place of [https://api.example.com/data'](https://api.example.com/data%27).

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const YourComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://api.example.com/data');
        // Process the successful response data here
        console.log(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Network Error:', error.message);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    // Your JSX code here
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incomplete. I can help you with the solution that I implemented. And the fix was enabling CORS at server side. I was using .NET API and allowed requests from my client address. You need to specify client addresses or specify * to allow request from all clients.

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                          .AllowAnyHeader()
                          .AllowAnyMethod();
                      });
});
```